# What will be the heuristic for the tower of Hanoi Question

Tags: greedy, heuristics

I want to implement python with python with different search algorithms. One of the algorithms is Greedy or A* that needs a heuristic function to work.

I cant think of any correct heuristic to work. Could someone suggest a heuristic?

Answer (score 0):

For search algorithms, like Greedy and A*, you need to implement the manhattan. It is used to compare distance of two point.

```
(n, m) = |xn − xm| + |yn − ym|
```